# VS Code showing 401 trying to load script and CSS assets in a Webview

Tags: javascript, typescript, cors, vscode-extensions, vscode-webview

### Summary

I'm trying to load an HTML page referencing local JS and CSS files into a Webview. Details below on the code I'm using to construct the URIs (the results don't look correct, but the code I believe matches other examples online). The Webview Developer Tools show 401 errors for the assets. How can I get these loaded?

### Details

I'm producing HTML with this in the `<head>`. (I have both logged this HTML as well as viewed the source elements through the Webview Developer tools to verify.)

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' https://*.vscode-cdn.net; script-src 'nonce-1CAM0Lr33whIXdLU4Rz5KKxJaq0hduY3'">
<link href="https://file%2B.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/baseeditorstyles.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
<script nonce="1CAM0Lr33whIXdLU4Rz5KKxJaq0hduY3" type='module'
        src="https://file%2B.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/editorglue.js"></script>
```

The URIs are being produced by this code:

```js
private resourceURI(file: string) {
    return vscode.Uri.joinPath(this.extensionURI, 'resources', file);
}

private webviewURI(file: string) {
    return this.panel.webview.asWebviewUri(this.resourceURI(file)).toString();
}

// …

const editorCSSURI = this.webviewURI('baseeditorstyles.css');
```

… where `extensionURI` is from `context.extensionUri` with contents: `{scheme: 'file', authority: '', path: '/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor', query: '', fragment: '', …}`. That `path` is correct.

As best I can tell, that's the same effective code path as shown in [this VS Code example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-sample/src/extension.ts#L177-L182) for generating the webview URI.

The result, however, is that every CSS and JS asset shows `net::ERR_ABORTED 401` in the Webview Developer Tools.

[image: Screenshot of Webview Developer tools showing the text shown immediately following this image]

```
GET https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/baseeditorstyles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 401
(anonymous) @ index.html?id=084ede1f-0484-44cf-8cd7-1b60312bd463&origin=cf31cd3f-41e9-41ea-861e-c867d65713ed&swVersion=4&extensionId=undefined_publisher.visual-scxml-editor&platform=electron&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&parentOrigin=vscode-file%3A%2F%2Fvscode-app:973
setTimeout (async)
onFrameLoaded @ index.html?id=084ede1f-0484-44cf-8cd7-1b60312bd463&origin=cf31cd3f-41e9-41ea-861e-c867d65713ed&swVersion=4&extensionId=undefined_publisher.visual-scxml-editor&platform=electron&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&parentOrigin=vscode-file%3A%2F%2Fvscode-app:971
(anonymous) @ index.html?id=084ede1f-0484-44cf-8cd7-1b60312bd463&origin=cf31cd3f-41e9-41ea-861e-c867d65713ed&swVersion=4&extensionId=undefined_publisher.visual-scxml-editor&platform=electron&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&parentOrigin=vscode-file%3A%2F%2Fvscode-app:1002
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

---

### Investigation

@Andrew below suggests that `asWebviewUri()` should be returning a URI with a scheme of `vscode-resource`. Modifying my `webviewURI()` function to output debug information:

```js
console.log({
   file,
   fileURI:this.resourceURI(file), 
   webURI:this.panel.webview.asWebviewUri(this.resourceURI(file))
})
```

…shows that it is in fact generating URIs with an `https` schema and an authority of `file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net`:

```
{file: 'neatxml.js', fileURI: f, webURI: f}
    file: 'neatxml.js'
    fileURI: f {scheme: 'file', authority: '', path: '/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/neatxml.js', query: '', fragment: '', …}
        _formatted: null
        _fsPath: null
        authority: ''
        fragment: ''
        fsPath: ƒ fsPath(){return this._fsPath||(this._fsPath=b(this,!1)),this._fsPath}
        path: '/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/neatxml.js'
        query: ''
        scheme: 'file'
    webURI: f {scheme: 'https', authority: 'file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net', path: '/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/neatxml.js', query: '', fragment: '', …}
        _formatted: null
        _fsPath: null
        authority: 'file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net'
        fragment: ''
        fsPath: ƒ fsPath(){return this._fsPath||(this._fsPath=b(this,!1)),this._fsPath}
        path: '/Users/phrogz/Code/visual-scxml-editor/resources/neatxml.js'
        query: ''
        scheme: 'https'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in the past it may have been that `asWebviewUri()` generated URIs with a `vscode-resource:` scheme, that is no longer true. The CORS policy generated by `this.panel.webview.cspSource` is properly aligned with the URIs it generates to work.

What is missing is that when `vscode.window.createWebviewPanel()` is called one must pass along `localResourceRoots` listing the location(s) where files may be loaded from. For example:

```js
const resourcesDir = vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, 'resources')const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
    'scxml', `SCXML ${path.basename(doc.fileName)}`,
    vscode.ViewColumn.Beside,
    {
        enableScripts: true,
        localResourceRoots: [resourcesDir]
    }
);
```

I actually *had* both `enableScripts` and `localResourceRoots` set, but due to a copy/paste error I was setting the directory to `'media'` instead of my actual `'resources'` directory.